# swap unique_ptr's (non-standard Microsoft C++ Extension)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, unique-ptr

I'm having trouble compiling this code:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(Type * new_ptr)
{
    myInternalUniquePtr_->swap(std::unique_ptr<Type>(new_ptr));
}
```

ReSharper said that `Binding r-value to l-value reference is non standard Microsoft C++ extension`. It seems to be correct because I cannot compile it in GCC, for example.

I've changed the code to this:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(Type * new_ptr)
{
    myInternalUniquePtr_->reset(new_ptr);
}
```

Is this acceptable?

**Update:** `reset` is calling deleter of old ptr. Does MS extension call the deleter of the previous value?

**Update2:** Checked, yes, it deletes old ptr value, but not in `swap` itself, but after function exists (thanks James)

Comment: I think yes. Btw, how can you call a code which uses C++11 legacy? :D

Comment: @Melkon, today is 2015, and code is from 2013. And with current rate of the language development even 2 years is enough to call it legacy :-)

Comment: the preferred way would be `void MyClass::MyMethod(std::unique_ptr<Type> new_ptr)` and `std::move`, which makes it clear to a caller what actually happens with `new_ptr`

Comment: @vladon Well, you are a lucky man, i mostly work in code bases which counted terrible even 10 years before... that's legacy. :D. 2013 seems pretty new. :P

Comment: I can't understand the new addition to this question.

Comment: @JamesRoot `std::unique_ptr::reset` calls deleter of its old value. Is MS extension of `std::unique_ptr::swap` calls deleter too? I'll check it now in web compiler.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/swap From this i think it should delete the object.

Comment: Microsoft didn't modify the standard library to allow rvalues to bind to lvalue references. They modified the compiler to extend the lifetime of rvalues bound to lvalue references when passed as parameters. FYI, the Microsoft extension treats the rvalue as if it is destroyed after the function exits, not before it enters.

Comment: @Melkon, yes, old value is destructed after swap.

Comment: I would be worried about the library writers if `unique_pointer` didn't clean up after itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *`reset` is calling deleter of old ptr. Does MS extension call the deleter of the previous value?*

`std::unique_ptr::swap` mutually transfers ownership of stored pointers between objects involved in a call. Thus, a pointer owned by `myInternalUniquePtr` is exchanged with the one from a temporary object, `std::unique_ptr<Type>(new_ptr)`, whose lifetime ends at the end of a full expression that it's part of. For a function call statement, this implies the destruction of this temporary at the point of `;`, which means that the pointer originally stored in `myInternalUniquePtr_` is freed after the statement execution (by a destructor of that temporary). The fact that VC++ allows a prvalue temporary to be bound by a non-const lvalue reference (which is a non-conforming feature) should not impact the above behavior.

The replacement:

```
myInternalUniquePtr_->reset(new_ptr);
```

is valid. However, it's unclear to a caller what happens inside `MyMethod`. A better option would be to force a caller to explicitly pass a `unique_ptr`, which makes it obvious that the function takes ownership of that pointer, and that it's not supposed to point, e.g., to an array.

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(std::unique_ptr<Type> new_ptr)
{
    myInternalUniquePtr_ = std::move(new_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Is assignment will call deleter of old `myInternalUniquePtr` value?

Comment: @vladon yes, the move-assignment frees the old value owned by `myInternalUniquePtr`